# Como calcular raízes de polinômios com uma lista?

Tags: python, lista

Eu estou tendo dificuldades com um trabalho da universidade e venho pedir ajuda de vocês aqui.

Tenho duas listas de valores candidatos a serem raízes de um polinômio.

```
    listaDivisoresP = []

for i in range(int(p[0])):
    if p[0]%(i+1) == 0:
        listaDivisoresP.append(i+1)

print(listaDivisoresP)

listaDivisoresN = []

for i in range (len(listaDivisoresP)):
    listaDivisoresN.append(-listaDivisoresP[i])

print(listaDivisoresN)
```

Como o código mostra, eu tenho uma lista com os valores dos candidatos positivos e uma outra com os valores dos candidatos negativos. Agora, eu queria pegar um polinômio que tem seus coeficientes dados por uma lista. Por exemplo, o polinômio:

```
                                             5x^4+3x^3-2x^2+x-2
```

Tem sua lista (p) indicada por:

```
                                             p[] = {5, 3, -2, 1, 2}
```

Com esse polinômio, eu quero testar todos os valores que estão nas listas para descobrir qual valor resultado em zero. Quando achar um valor que resultado em zero, eu quero criar uma nova lista (listaRaizesInteiras) com os valores que zeram o polinômio. Para isso, eu tentei o seguinte:

```
listaRaizInteira = []
listaTesteRaizes = []

for i in range(len(listaDivisoresP) - 1):
    contador   = len (p) - 1
    while contador > 0:
        raiz = (listaDivisoresP[i]**(contador)) * p[contador]
        listaTesteRaizes.append(raiz)
        contador = contador - 1
    if sum(listaTesteRaizes)  + p[0] == 0:
        listaRaizInteira.append(listaDivisoresP[i])
```

Porém, não estou conseguindo obter a lista que desejo. No caso, eu só testei para os valores positivos (usando a listaDivisoresP), pois com os valores negativos (da listaDivisoresN) seria bastante similiar.

Alguém pode me auxiliar a conseguir fazer o que estou tentando?

Answer (score 0):

No seu exemplo a equação não possui raízes reais.

```
5x^4+3x^3-2x^2+x-2 => Raízes imaginárias.
```

Por isso troquei pela Equação:

```
x^6 -3x^5 -6x^4 +10x^3 +21x^2 + 9x  => Raizes: -1, 0, 3
```

Segue um código que faz o que você quer.
Ele gera duas listas de números candidatos, uma lista de números candidatos negativos, e uma lista de números candidatos positivos. Ele testa todos os candidatos na função, se o resultado for zero quer dizer que encontrou uma raíz e  adiciona o valor em uma lista de raízes encontradas.

```
# Função que representa o polinômio
# Passar lista de coeficientes e o valor de x
# Retorna o valor do polinômio em x
def funcao(coeficientes, x):
    expoente = len(coeficientes)-1
    resultado = 0
    for c in coeficientes:
        resultado = resultado + c * x ** expoente
        expoente=expoente-1
    return resultado

# LISTA COM CANDIDATOS POSITIVOS
numeros_positivos = []
for i in range(0,100,1):
    numeros_positivos.append(i)

# LISTA COM CANDIDATOS NEGATIVOS
numeros_negativos = []
for i in range(-1,-100,-1):
    numeros_negativos.append(i)

# CRIA LISTA DE COEFICIENTES DA FUNÇÃO
# Equação: 1x^6 -3x^5 -6x^4 +10x^3 +21x^2 + 9x
coeficientes = [ 1, -3, -6, 10, 21, 9, 0  ] 

# TESTA OS RESULTADOS, ARMAZENA RAIZES EM UMA LISTA
raizes = []
for x in numeros_positivos:
    if funcao(coeficientes,x) == 0:
        raizes.append(x)

for x in numeros_negativos:
    if funcao(coeficientes,x) == 0:
        raizes.append(x)

# PRINTA AS RAIZES ENCONTRADAS -1, 0, e 3
print(raizes)
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!